# When using Proof of Stake, why does a block header need to be signed by the miner?

Tags: blockchain

I am reading the following article about PoS

http://earlz.net/view/2017/07/27/1904/the-missing-explanation-of-proof-of-stake-version

In this article, the author says

> The block hash must be signed by the public key in the staking transaction's second vout

Why is this necessary? When using PoS, because the coin stake transaction's input comes from the miner, so the miner already provides an unlocking script on the inputs of the coin stake transaction. Why does she need to sign the block?

A reference implementation can be found in PIVX:

```
class CBlock : public CBlockHeader
{
public:
// network and disk
std::vector<CTransaction> vtx;

// ppcoin: block signature - signed by one of the coin base txout[N]'s owner
std::vector<unsigned char> vchBlockSig;
```

where `vchBlockSig` stores the signature which is signed by

```
key.Sign(block.GetHash(), block.vchBlockSig)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the PoW systems, block signing is not needed, because of block ID id generating by hashing root of Merkle Tree (Merkle Root) of payload transactions and nonce, until hash become less than target.

If do analogous approach in PoS system, them malicious minter can generate lot of attempts with different output hashes from a same kernel UTXO (transaction output, which mints coins) - just by modify nonce and/or rearrange transaction in Merkle Tree, there is lot of combinations. And by this way, he can reduce PoS to PoW (lot of hashing attempts with same data).

To prevent such degradation, PoS cryptos (PPC, EMC, etc) limits number of attempts for some specific UTXO. And hash result (which compared to a target) depends only from kernel UTXO and from current time, and independent from nonce, block payload, and so. As result, PoS minter can make a single attempt for each matured UTXO only once per second.

But, with this approach, block content is not participate in the kernel hash, which compares to target.

As result, if minter does not sign a block, malicious actor can do following attack: He can intercept from the network a freshly-minted block from a minter, modify payload transactions and Merkle Tree and block hash (for example, add double spend TX), and redistribute the modified block over the network. Such block will contains valid coinstake transaction (which spends kernel UTXO), and will be accepted by network nodes.

To prevent this "modify freshly-minted block on the fly", block is signed by address of kernel UTXO. By this signature, minter provides a proof: Block is created by same minter, who generates a coinstake TX.

Thus, with PoS, block generation is following:

- Find appropriate kernel UTXO
- Generate coinstake transaction, which sends coins from kernel UTXO address to itself.
- Create a new block,contains this coinstake TX and payload TXes
- Sign this block with coin address of kernel UTXO.

Practically, enough to sign just a header, contains Merkle Root.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My understanding is that the malicious actor will most likely modify the output of the coin stake transaction to send the reward to himself.

Comment: Malicious actor unable to modify coinstake output, as same as he unable modify output of any other transaction, received into mempool. If he does this, he invalidates TX signature, and transaction become invalid.

Comment: I understood what you mean. No one is able to modify a tx because each input of a transaction contains a signature. Then my question becomes what are the incentives for the malicious actor to modifying a PoS block? By modifying a block, the malicious actor is likely to create a fork of the chain, and then after some time, forking will be resolved, so the effect of the malicious act will be in vain.

Comment: Yes, fork will be resolved. But with high probability - toward malicious actor, i.e. his updated block will be accepted as "trusted". By this action, Malicious "stealing" minting power from innocent minter. If he does it systematically - he can consolidate high "minting power", and create 51% attack.